# Exception Handling in java

Tags: java

i was trying to run the following code but i am getting error please clarify my doubt

```
import java.util.*;

    class Except 
    { public class AlfaException extends Exception{}
      public static void main(String[] args)
       {

        int b;
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
          try
            { 
              b=s.nextInt();
            }
          catch(InputMismatchException ex)
               {
                 try
                     {
                        if(('b'> 67)&&('b'<83)){}
                     }
                 catch(AlfaException e){
                   throw new AlfaException("hello");
                    }         
                 System.out.println("error found");
               }
        }
    }  



 Except.java:20: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static cont
ext
               throw new AlfaException("hello");
                     ^
```

1 error

Comment: I wonder why I cannot edit or even retag this question

Comment: @eng Because someone with a reputation lower than 2000 has already edited the question and the edit hasn't been approved by users with a higher reputation.

Comment: Alternatively, you can throw the exception as follows: `new Except().new AlphaException();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Static context is a context that runs on class without actual instance of that class. Your main method is static, that means it can only access **static** variables. However, your AlfaException is **not** static. Meaning that it will be bound to an **instance** of `Except` class - which you do not have.

Therefore you have 2 choises:

1. Make AlfaException also static: `public static class AlfaException extends Exception{}`. That will make it reside in static scope so it will be possible to access it from static functions.
2. Move all the `main(...)` method logic into non-static context. Create a function called `doWork()` that is not static, move all the code from `main` to `doWork`, and then call it like this:

.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Except instance = new Except();
    instance.doWork();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your AlfaException is a non-static inner class of Except, so it can only be instantiated from inside an *instance* of Except. The main method is static, so doesn't have an enclosing instance.

Change the declaration of AlfaException to:

```
public static class AlfaException extends Exception{}
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of mistakes:

1. `AlfaException` is never thrown in your `try`-block
2. `AlfaException` is a non-static inner class of `Except` (see other answers)
3. If you rethrow `AlfaException` in `catch`-block, the `main` needs a `throws` like this:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws AlfaException { ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

class Except 
{ public static class AlfaException extends Exception{

    public AlfaException(String string) {
        super();
    }
}
  public static void main(String[] args) throws AlfaException
   {

    int b;
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
      try
        { 
          System.out.println("Enter the value for b");
          b=s.nextInt();
          System.out.println("b value is "+b);
        }
      catch(InputMismatchException ex)
           {
             if(('b'> 67)&&('b'<83)){}         
             System.out.println("error found");
           }
    }
}
```

output:
   Enter the value for b
   80b
   error found